# Using Liquibase CLI to update PostgreSQL database on Git push

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I'm looking into using Liquibase to manage updates to my PostgreSQL table & functions. I'm not integrating into a Java application, so I'm using it 'standalone', meaning defining a changeset in a SQL file and executing it using Liquibase CLI. Is there a way to automate things so that when I check-in the changelog.sql file into Git that Liquibase can execute it against the database I want?

If this isn't possible, I will simply manually use the CLI, that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable. I do something like this in my Jenkins Pipeline.

### Configuring liquibase

- Make sure that you have liquibase installed
- Download the `postgresql-X.X-XXX.jdbc3.jar` file and put it in the `lib` folder inside your liquibase folder. This makes it globally available to liquibase.

### Running when you commit something

- Open your git controlled project folder and navigate to the folder `.git/hooks`. Depending on your git flavor there may be some files in here already. You can read more on the net about ow this works: https://githooks.com/
- Create an empty text file and name it `post-commit`.
- Add the following (presumes that you are using git for windows or git on linux - I am not sure if it works for all git implementations)

```
    #!/bin/bash
    DB_PORT        = 6000
    SQL_DB_NAME    = "mydbName"
    PGSQL_USERNAME = "username"
    PGSQL_PASSWORD = "password"

    /path/to/liquibase --driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver --changeLogFile=../resources/database/db.changelog-1.1.xml --url=\"jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:${DB_PORT}/${SQL_DB_NAME}?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC\" --username=${PGSQL_USERNAME} --password=${PGSQL_PASSWORD} update
```

### Notes

This will run EVERY TIME YOU COMMIT. if you are using some remote git server like github/bitbucket consider `pre-push` instead of `post-commit`

This might need some tweeking. 
* I am using the xml files in this example
* This is adapted from what I use for MySQL so the jdbc url may need to be changed.

### Potential improvements

Check through the commited files and only if there is a .sql file, run the liquibase.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done, but you will a maven build server to perform the update.

I would do it this way:

- Configure your project as a pseudo-java application with maven. You will need a pom file. Example below.
- Setup a build server that can run maven builds. You can find a list of capable servers [here](https://maven.apache.org/continuous-integration.html).
- Setup a web hook on Git push to tell the build server to fetch your updated scripts and the build. If you were using Github, instructions [here](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/).
- Configure your build server to run the maven target 'liquibase:update'.

**Example pom file (adapt as required):**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <scm>
        <url>https://github.com/{user}/{repository}</url>
        <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/{user}/{repository}git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/{user}/{repository}</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

    <name>My Project</name>
    <description>Simlpe pom file to run my liquibase scripts</description>

    <properties>
        <liquibase-maven-plugin.version>3.5.1</liquibase-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>liquibase-maven.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Example liquibase-maven.properties file:**

```
changeLogFile=changelog.xml 
driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
username=user
password=password
verbose=true
dropFirst=false
url=jdbc:mysql://database-server:3306/schema
databaseChangeLogLockTableName=databasechangeloglock
databaseChangeLogTableName=databasechangelog
```

I hope this helps, this is in no manner a complete recipe to get it working, but it should set you on the right path if you keep at it.

**Alternative**
If you really want to use the liquibase CLI, you could script this. For example setup a simple CGI capable web server (Apache) and write a script that would do a pull from your git repo before running the liquibase CLI update. You would then setup the Git web hook to make the request that triggers the update script.

In fact, now that I write this alternative, that is probably a simpler solution to the build server above. I guess it depends on your current available architecture and what you would be most comfortable with. First solution is all about configuration, this one would require writing a small script.

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase itself doesn't have something like this. I would suggest looking at something like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) to automate this process.